# "Disclaimer: mock-up screens employ source material from the internet under fair-use policy"

Tags: meaning, sentence

Does the sentence in the title make sense?

I have a document where I have inserted some mock-up screens that I created myself. However, the screens consist of graphics which I downloaded from the internet and of which I don't own the copyright (they all come from well-known franchises, say *Star Wars*).

I just want to state - at the end of the document - that I aknowledge these aren't mine but I am using them under "fair-use" policy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an English sentence, it absolutely makes sense. As a legal disclaimer, it is absolutely worthless.

There is no such thing as a "fair-use" policy legally. What you are doing is to take copyrighted materials without permission, and you seem to have a policy of claiming that there is some "fair-use" rule that allows you to do this. There is a "fair-use" affirmative defence when you are taken to court for copyright infringement, but I can't see how that would apply to your case.

Comment: "fair use" is an actual legal doctrine, in the US at least: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_use I'm not sure whether it applies to the poster's website: i suspect not.  It is, however, still a legal defense.

Comment: The ratio of content about the English Language in this answer seems pitifully low.

Comment: It's not from a website, it's a document with some ideas of mine where I have added some screens for clarity. That's all. I don't suppose someone will come after me, to be honest I just want the reader to know that I aknowledge the source material is not mine. BTW, I am excited the sentence does make sense, I didn't know I could write stuff this complex without errors :-)